# Setting Vim theme by Dayle Rees

Tags: macos, vim, themes

I have a problem setting a theme from by Daylee Rees (https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes) for Vim (term/MacVim).

When I choose the theme say "Lavender Contrast" -

`colorscheme Lavendar Contrast`

I get an error saying the theme cannot be found. Wherein single-worded theme names like `colorscheme Goldfish' is getting set without any problem.

The whole list of themes and how they look is found here:
https://daylerees.github.io/

I tried putting Lavender_Contrast, Lavender-Contrast, etc, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained under `:help :colorscheme`, the argument of `:colorscheme` is the filename without the extension:

> This searches 'runtimepath' for the file "colors/{name}.vim".

so there is no reason whatsoever to try anything else.

In this case, the filename is `lavender-contrast.vim` so the correct command is:

```
:colorscheme lavender-contrast
```

Note that, if your system is *case-insensitive*, `Lavender-Contrast`, `LAVender-contrAST`, or any other case permutation may also be valid arguments but that would be silly.